# Google App Engine, using Logs API to meter users' bandwidth

Tags: google-app-engine, logging

I'm creating an app in GAE that will allow users to create websites. I will be charging them based on their bandwidth usage. I'm wondering exactly how to meter their account. I've looked at the Logs API and noticed the response_size parameter. I could simply tally each user's account this way, but I'm wondering how accurate this is and how it handles multi-media.

1) Is the response_size parameter accurate for metering bandwidth in this manner, does it include everything that I will eventually be billed for; headers etc...

2) If a page has a images/media from cloud storage in img or other tags isn't this technically a different request for storage.googleapis.com, are these downloads logged as part of the original request, separately as part of cloud storage, or not at all? If separate can I track which files have been downloaded how many times?

3) Same as #2, but for direct download files, ex: a user creates a page with a link to a PDF file storage in cloud storage, and it is downloaded several times by end users.

4) What if its a progressive download video/audio file and the end user doesn't watch or download the whole thing, is the partial download size logged?

This kind of metering might be to advanced for GAE, not sure. I've just started exploring GAE from AWS.

5) Do you have any other infrastructures or methods to consider if this is not possible in GAE?

Comment: Please try it yourself and post the results.  One has to run actual tests to be sure, because documentation might be wrong.  I would also like to know the answers.

Comment: Yup, looks like I will have to. Won't be until next week before I have time.